# What is this e mail really saying

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Veteran investigator Ken Smith had been following a suspicious e mail trail between John Jones and Robert Brooks.This particular one caught his attention. He was trying to figure it out.

From: Jjones@row.com

To:  Rbrooks@coolmail.com

Subject: Your last e mail on Money Issues

> Your option is to call Brad, Uma yourself.
>
> *Meet Kate Rove Now.*
>
> Other option is to put these assets for sale
>
> *Land At Cabo ,      Town Inn*

Comment: Are you sure cipher is an appropriate tag?

Comment: what else? just a riddle?

Comment: Is there any aspect of steganography in this puzzle?

Answer (score -3):

I think it is:

> Get a loan from the Shark or sell the Properties he(jones) had always
>  been interested in

Comment: Please use spoilers so as to let other users try and answers with no explanation are expected to be deleted.